# Serialize to JSON as name-value from String by Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some String, like:

```
String value = "123";
```

And when i serialize this string to json via ObjectMapper:

```
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
```

Output is:

```
"123"
```

Is it possible to write String using either string name and string value? Desired output:

```
"value" : "123"
```

PS: i dont want to create DTO object with one field for serializing one String value.

Comment: If you dont have an object but only this single variable: I'd asssemble the String simple manually ( "\"value\" : \"" + value + '"') Otherwise you have an Object which will be serialized just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use the Jackson JsonGenerator

```
try (JsonGenerator generator = new JsonFactory().createGenerator(writer)) {
     generator.writeStartObject();
     generator.writeFieldName("value");
     generator.writeString("123");
     generator.writeEndObject();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a plain string you'll get out a plain string when serialised. If you want to wrap it in an object then use a map for the simplest solution.

```
String value = "123";
Map<String, String> obj = new HashMap<>();
obj.put("value", value);
```

Passing that through the mapper will produce something like this:

```
{ "value": "123" }
```

If you change the map to `<String, Object>` you can pass in pretty much anything you want, even maps within maps and they'll serialise correctly.

If you really can't have the enclosing curly braces you can always take the substring but that would be a very weird use case if you're still serialising to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Map:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("value", value);
String parsedValue = ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(map);
```

and you will get: `{"value":"123"}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 and want to do it in automated way without creating maps or manually putting string variable name "value", this is the [link](https://www.concretepage.com/java/jdk-8/java-8-reflection-access-to-parameter-names-of-method-and-constructor-with-maven-gradle-and-eclipse-using-parameters-compiler-argument) you need to follow-